# Remove a header from OAuthSwift before a POST

Tags: swift, alamofire, moya

I'm using OAuthSwiftAlamofire which takes OAuthSwift and adds a SessionManager that plugs into AlamoFire. On top of that, I'm using Moya for my calls. Everything works fine except that OAuthSwift is injecting

```
"Content-Type"="whatever"
```

This causes the Twitter API to return

```
{"errors":[{"code":32,"message":"Could not authenticate you."}]}
```

I modified Moya's `endpointClosure` to set the "Content-Type" header to nil, but that didn't accomplish it.

Anybody know how to erase this header before the request is sent using Moya->Alamofire->OAuthSwiftAlamofire->OAuthSwift?

Answer (score 0):

Not the most satisfactory solution, but I just edited Alamofire and OAuthSwift's source code to check for my condition before appending those tags.

Note, however, that this didn't solve my problem with that error. Still getting it without the ContentType tag.